# Skip generation of readonly fields for Html.ActionLink

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, reflection, extension-methods

I have a base request-object `RequestBase` defined like:

```
public abstract class RequestBase
{
    public abstract string Area { get; }
    public abstract string ActionName { get; }
    public abstract string LinkName { get; }
    public abstract string ControllerName { get; }
}
```

and a childclass of this like:

```
public class RequestTest : RequestBase
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public RequestTest()
    {
        Id = Guid.Empty;
    }

    #region implementation of RequestBase

    public override string Area
    {
        get { return "MyArea"; }
    }

    public override string ActionName
    {
        get { return "Overview"; }
    }

    public override string ControllerName
    {
        get { return "Test"; }
    }

    public override string LinkName
    {
        get { return "Click me for awesome"; }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Question. I want to write a helper to build links this way:

```
@Html.ActionLinkByRequest(new RequestTest{Id = Guid.Empty})
```

which I currently have implemented

```
public static MvcHtmlString ActionLinkByRequest(this HtmlHelper helper, RequestBase request, object htmlAttributes = null)
{
    return helper.ActionLink(request.LinkName, request.ActionName, request.ControllerName, request, htmlAttributes);
}
```

Unfortunately it renders to:

```
<a href="/MyArea/Test/Overview?EventId=00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000&ActionName=Overview&LinkName=Click%20me%20for%20awesome&ControllerName=Test">Click me for awesome</a>
```

but I want to have only

```
<a href="/MyArea/Test/Overview?EventId=00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000">Click me for awesome</a>
```

without the readonly fields. Because they are readonly, I don't need them explicitly in the query-string as of my `Action` awaits the concrete implementation `RequestTest` and will have them anyway:

```
public ActionResult Overview(RequestTest request)
{
    // do things here

    return View();
}
```

Any ideas how I can skip the generation of read-only fields for the actionlink? Maybe by using reflection somehow?

**Edit by comments**

Would this work?

```
public static MvcHtmlString ActionLinkByRequest(this HtmlHelper helper, RequestBase request, object htmlAttributes = null)
{
    var rvd = new RouteValueDictionary();

    foreach(var prop in request.GetType().GetProperties().Where(p => p.CanRead && p.CanWrite))
    {
        // add the property by name and the value
        // rvd.Add(prop.Name, prop.GetValue());
    }

    // add the area (check if not already existing)
    if(!rvd.ContainsKey("Area"))
        rvd.Add("Area", request.AreaName);

    return helper.ActionLink(request.LinkName, request.ActionName, request.ControllerName, request, htmlAttributes);
}
```

Comment: Why are you passing the entire request object as the 4th parameter in your helper?

Comment: What should be passed instead?

Comment: Only the values you need to route, which I'm guessing is more like `new {Id=request.id}`

Comment: But I don't know the needed values as of each implementation can have it's own one. Or may I create a new `RouteValueDictionary` with only properties of the concrete request-implementation and add the area by "hand"?

Comment: So you are going to extend the RequestBase to include more properties.  I see.  I don't see where you've defined any properties as being readonly, so I don't see how you can filter them out programatically.  You might be able to handle some of this via routing as well.

Comment: By readonly I mean the abstract properties with `get` only which need to be implemented by childclass. E.g. the property `Id` is only relevant for the concrete `RequestTest` instance

Comment: I see.  Would converting your object properties to a RouteValueDictionary and hard coding it to remove LinkController, LinkName, and ActionLink work for you before passing it on into the ActionLink helper?

Comment: I've updated the question (Edit by comments)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the comments by Robert, I came up with the following that works for me:

```
public static MvcHtmlString ActionLinkByRequest(this HtmlHelper helper, RequestBase request, object htmlAttributes = null)
{
    // create new value-dictionary to be passed
    var rvd = new RouteValueDictionary();

    // loop through properties of the request
    foreach (var prop in request.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public).Where(p => p.CanRead && p.CanWrite))
    {
        // add name/value to route-dictionary
        rvd.Add(prop.Name, prop.GetValue(request));
    }

    // check if area is needed
    if (!rvd.ContainsKey("Area"))
    {
        rvd.Add("Area", request.Area);
    }

    return helper.ActionLink(request.LinkText, request.ActionName, request.ControllerName, rvd, HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(htmlAttributes));
}
```

Comment: This should work as well.  I'm just not a big fan of using reflection, especially in things that are low level.  Reflection isn't the quickest of things to do (or so I think, perhaps I should actually benchmark it someday).

Comment: @RobertMcKee I know that reflection may not be the most performant solution for many cases. In my case I'm not going to create hundreds of links so I'm pretty fine with reflection here ;)

Answer (score 2):

```
public static MvcHtmlString ActionLinkByRequest(this HtmlHelper helper, RequestBase request, object htmlAttributes = null)
{
    var rvd = new RouteValueDictionary(request);
    rvd.Remove("ActionName");
    rvd.Remove("ControllerName");
    rvd.Remove("LinkName");
    return helper.ActionLink(request.LinkName, request.ActionName, request.ControllerName, rvd, HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(htmlAttributes));
}
```

Comment: `HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(htmlAttributes)` should do the trick

Comment: Yup, was just checking to make sure that it was a public method.